# strict.lua - How do find out where the error occurred?

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x

I am using strict.lua in a cocos2d-x project under Xcode. When I get an error it doesn't tell me where the error occurred. I just get an error message like:

```
cocos2d: LUA ERROR: attempt to call a number value
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (...<folder>/strict.lua:30: attempt to index a nil value)
```

How can I get strict.lua to tell me where the error occurred or give me a call stack?

(Note putting print(debug.traceback()) in strict.lua doesn't work)

Comment: Check what function this is in line 30 in strict.lua. Then search your lua scripts for any calls to this. Add debug.traceback to those. Also check whether the debug module is imported/loaded in the first place (ie `print("debug is: " .. debug)` to test whether it's nil).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: That will raise an error even if `debug` is not `nil`. I think you meant `print("debug is:", debug)` (but this could trigger a `strict.lua` error if `debug` is not defined).

Comment: Sorry, haven't been using Lua for a while. Though `print("debug is: " .. tostring(debug))` ought to work even if debug is not defined.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: Better, but still the same possible `strict.lua`-error. Use `print("debug is: " .. tostring(rawget(_G, "debug")))` to avoid that (assuming that `print`, `tostring`, `rawget`, and `_G` are guaranteed to be available).

Comment: panic errors like those usually come from uncaught lua errors and exceptions that's allowed to propagate into C land. Are you embedding lua into your app or writing some kind of lua C module?